# reflect-metadata and querying the object for decorators

Tags: typescript

I have a decorator that simply does nothing:

```
export function myDecorator(target: any, key: string) {
   var t = Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, key);
}
```

I use this decorator with a property of a class:

```
export class SomeClass {

    @globalVariable
    someProperty: string;

    @globalVariable
    fakeProperty: number;
}
```

Now, what I want to do is, get all the properties of the class decorated with the @globalVariable decorator.

I tried using "reflect-metadata" with:

```
Reflect.getMetadata('globalVariable', this);
```

but all I get is "undefined". Is this possible with reflect-metadata or am I getting this totally wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Property decorators are called once per property definition within a class, when the class is defined.

This means that if you decorate the properties in SomeClass with @myDecorator:

```
export class SomeClass {
    @myDecorator
    someProperty: string;
}
```

Then the myDecorator function will be called with:
target: ( the SomeClass definition )
key : ( the name of the property )

When you enable metadata through the "emitDecoratorMetadata" property, the TypeScript compiler will generate the following metadata properties:

`'design:type'`, `'design:paramtypes'` and `'design:returntype'`.

This then allows you to call Reflect.getMetadata with any of the above keys.  i.e:

```
Reflect.getMetadata('design:type', ...)
Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes',...)
Reflect.getMetadata('design:returntype', ...)
```

You cannot call Reflect.getMetadata with the name of the decorator.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What about enumerating all the decorated properties of a class?

Comment: I believe that you would need to create your own decorator to store this information.  Remember that a property decorator is simply a function that is called once per decorated property.  If you stored this information, you would be able to retrieve it later...

Comment: Did you ever do @blorkfish's last comment? That happens to be exactly what i need.

Comment: @blorkfish is there a doc for this?

Answer (score 4):

What you need is to implement globalVariable in the following way:

```js
function globalVariable(target: any, propertyKey: string | Symbol): void {
    let variables = Reflect.getOwnMetadata("globalVariable", target.constructor) || [];
    variables.push(propertyKey);
    Reflect.defineMetadata("globalVariable", variables, target.constructor);
}
```

Then, on run time, you'll be able to call

```js
Reflect.getMetadata('globalVariable', this);
```

as you wanted.